# Can I change discord-server's owner nickname with bot?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Is it possible to change nickname with bot for discord server's owner?

Upd.
I have e server. I want give my bot right to change my nickname. Can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer: No.

Discord's permission system does not allow for any member of the server to change the nickname of the owner (or other members who have a higher top role) regardless of if they are a bot or not.