# Discord py missing permission for change nick_name

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

my bot cant rename me because im guild owner. Is there a way to bypass this missing permission error ? And allow the bot to rename me even if im guild owner?

my code

```
@bot.command()
async def register(ctx,*, pseudo):
    idd = ctx.message.author.id
    database_handler.register(idd,pseudo)
    elo = database_handler.get_elo(idd)
    await ctx.message.author.edit(nick   = f"[{elo}] {pseudo}")
    await ctx.send("Successfully registered !")
```

error

```
Ignoring exception in command register:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mattm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\mattm\Desktop\botdiscord\MMR6\main.py", line 52, in register
    await ctx.message.author.edit(nick   = f"[{elo}] {pseudo}")
  File "C:\Users\mattm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 681, in edit
    await http.edit_member(guild_id, self.id, reason=reason, **payload)
  File "C:\Users\mattm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mattm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\mattm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mattm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I change discord-server's owner nickname with bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45251598/can-i-change-discord-servers-owner-nickname-with-bot)

Comment: yes it does thanks

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot have your nickname changed by a user account or a bot account, as the owner of the guild, you are above everyone on the hierarchy, meaning you cannot be moderated and because of that, you cannot have your nickname changed, without you doing it yourself.